# How to divide two integers without getting 0?

Tags: division, presto

My goal is two divide two integers in Presto 0.212, e. g. 1/2. The naive approach `SELECT 1/2` returns 0. Next, I tried `SELECT CAST(1/2 AS DOUBLE)`, but this also returns 0. How to divide 1/2 such that 0.5 is returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Presto, but my guess is that in the example you've provided `1/2` is being evaluated as an integer then is being cast as a double. Maybe something along the lines of `SELECT CAST(1 AS DOUBLE)/CAST(2 AS DOUBLE)` or you maybe you could just add `.0` to the end of your numbers like `SELECT 1.0/2.0`. Just a few shots in the dark from me.

Comment: Both work, but as I want to divide columns I choose the first one.

Comment: In Presto (following SQL standard), `2.0` is not a `double`, it's of `decimal(2,1)` type. This affects results: `10 / 3e0` prints `3.3333333333333335`, while `10 / 3.0` prints `3.3`. Use scientific notation or explicit type construct to get "2 as double": `2e0` or `double '2'`.